# RAW column first bytes cut off

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a problem with binary data, I have a C# code which insert binary data into table, column type is `RAW(64)`, in some case some bytes are missing. I found out that the problem is if my data start with `0xFFFE`, I was able to create such situation in sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BlobTable(
    testData BLOB
);
```

then I insert records:

```sql
INSERT INTO BlobTable VALUES(hextoraw('FFFE01'));
INSERT INTO BlobTable VALUES(hextoraw('01'));
INSERT INTO BlobTable VALUES(hextoraw('FFFF01'));
INSERT INTO BlobTable VALUES(hextoraw('FFFEFFFEFFFE01'));
```

then I do:

```sql
SELECT DUMP ( CAST ( testData AS RAW( 128 ) ) ) FROM BlobTable;
```

and the result is:

```
Typ=23 Len=1: 1
Typ=23 Len=1: 1
Typ=23 Len=3: 255,255,1
Typ=23 Len=5: 255,254,255,254,1
```

So belive that te problem is `0xFFFE` bytes at the beginning, in both cases when I convert those bytes to RAW, first `0xFFFE` is missing. Do you have any idea why this is happening? Also I'm wondering if any other combination of bytes creates same situation.

Comment: It is coming across as a unusable unicode character - 
http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/FFFE.html
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/904803/character-data-is-represented-incorrectly-when-the-code-page-of-the-cl

Comment: Yep , but 
1) RAW should not be interpreted in any way
`The RAW and LONG RAW datatypes are used for data that is not to be interpreted (not converted when moving data between different systems) by Oracle Database.` 
2) why it skips only first \uFFFE

Comment: I read the RAW data type again and I agree that your interpretation seems like it should be correct.  I'm not sure why it is doing this, just that it is.  The microsoft support link showed a possible work around at the end that I was hoping might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I like `Method 3: Use the binary data type or the varbinary data type` but as I understand RAW is varbinary  for Oracle. And this problem do not exists when I use varbinary in MsSQL.

Comment: Which Oracle version? It works for me perfectly fine on 11.2

Comment: I have this problem on 
 Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit

Comment: Have you tried casting the data as varbinary?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I've check this code on Oracle 11.2g and it works fine , then I checked on https://livesql.oracle.com and I got exactly same result as posted. Maybe there is a bug in newest version of Oracle?

Comment: Yes, I suspect a bug and I recommend to contact support.

Comment: I've raised an issue to Oracle , we will see. Anyway , thanks @MarmiteBomber for an info that it works fine on older version ,that helped me to identify that problem might be not in my code.

Comment: I've got feedback from Oracle , 'Newer Oracle versions interpret these bytes as metadata.' , so basically they've added something but there is nothing about that in documentation as it says that RAW should not interpret data inside